# IPython notebook shortcut to run

Tags: python

I am currious if there is a shortcut for runing the  selected cell in IPython notebook such as alt+F5 or ctrl+f5 or something simmiliar  that is present in Visual Studio (I don't recall exactly now ) , cause I found it annoing to go with  the mouse on  the run  button every  time I need to run a cell?

Comment: Try shift+enter.

Answer (score 2):

[IPython notebook Keyboard shortcuts](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/notebook.html#keyboard-shortcuts):

- `Shift-Enter`: run cell
- `Ctrl-Enter`: run cell in-place
- `Alt-Enter`: run cell, insert below
- `Ctrl-m`: This is the prefix for all other shortcuts, which consist of Ctrl-m followed by a single letter or character. For example, if you type Ctrl-m h (that is, the sole letter h after Ctrl-m), IPython will show you all the available keyboard shortcuts.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

IPython notebook Keyboard shortcuts[image: IPython notebook]

![Option the options [2:4] i think is the answer to your question.]

Comment: That is great , tnks!